# Get the x and z axis values from impulse or step plot functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a model/system in Matlab and I can use impulse or step functions to find out the impulse or step response of that system.

**Example of system:**

```
a = [-0.5572 -0.7814;0.7814  0];
b = [1 -1;0 2];
c = [1.9691  6.4493];
sys = ss(a,b,c,0);
impulse(sys)
```

**The plot is:**

[image]

Now I have plotted the response of the system and I am trying to import the x and y axis values into the Matlab workspace so that I can continue further processing.

Can someone tell me how this reverse methodology to plot function works here ?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more information. Please check out [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Please show what you have, and explain where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`impulse` and `step` can be used [with two or three output arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/impulse.html):

```
[y,t] = impulse(sys);
figure 
plot(t,y(:,:,1),t,y(:,:,2));
[y,t] = step(sys);
figure 
plot(t,y(:,:,1),t,y(:,:,2));
```

> For state-space models only:
>
> ```
> [y,t,x] = impulse(sys)
> ```
>
> (length of t) × (number of outputs) × (number of inputs)
>   and `y(:,:,j)` gives the response to an impulse disturbance entering the jth input channel. Similarly, the dimensions of x are
>   (length of t) × (number of states) × (number of inputs)

Comment: First of all thanks. Sorry for this follow up question, but just wondering can you give a hint on, how can I select the "y" values only at certain values of "x" ?

Comment: @statisticalbeginner You can use logical indexing. For example,  you can use the code `y1= y(:,:,1); plot(t(t>10),y1(t>10));` to plot the `y1`data for t>10